# @UsePipes(ValidationPipe) not working with generics (abstract controller)

Tags: node.js, typescript, oop, generics, nestjs

I am building an API using **Nest.js** and MySQL. Due to agility and DRY principles, I am creating an OOP structure which sets all the basic CRUD endpoints for a given Entity (from TypeORM). The main goal is to avoid writing the same common methods for different Entities.

To achieve that, I'm using a strategy with *TypeScript Generics*. I still have to create all the common files (`.controller.ts`, `.service.ts`, `.module.ts`, `.entity.ts`) for each Entity, but I don't have to write its methods. Instead, I just extends two classes: `RestController` and `RestService`. These classes already implements the common methods, but I have to pass some *T types* as parameters so TypeORM can inject the right repository to the Service.

**The problem:** The `@UsePipes` decorator is not being called when I use it in the parent class (`RestController`), but it works normally when I overwrite de *RestController* create method in the child class (`SubcategoriesController`).

**rest.controller.ts:**

```
import { Get, Post, Body, Param, Put, Delete, UsePipes, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RestService } from './rest.service';
import { ObjectLiteral } from 'typeorm';

export abstract class RestController<T, C = T, U = T> {
  constructor(protected service: RestService<T, C, U>) {}

  @Get()
  async index(): Promise<T[]> {
    return this.service.getAll();
  }

  @Post('create')
  @UsePipes(ValidationPipe) //HERE!
  async create(@Body() data: C): Promise<T> {
    return this.service.create(data as C);
  }
}
```

**rest.service.ts:**

```
import { Repository, UpdateResult, DeleteResult, Entity, DeepPartial } from 'typeorm';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

export interface RestClass<T, C = T, U = T> {
  // Properties
  repository: Repository<T>;

  // Default Methods
  getAll(): Promise<T[]>;
  create(model: T | C | U): Promise<T>;
}

export class RestService<T, C = T, U = T> implements RestClass<T, C, U> {
  constructor(
    public repository: Repository<T>,
  ) {}

  getAll = async () => {
    return await this.repository.find({relations:: this.repository.metadata.ownRelations.map(r => r.propertyName)});
  }

  create = async (model: C) => {
    return await this.repository.save(model as C);
  }
}
```

And here is how I set a real entity endpoints, extending the above classes:

**subcategories.controller.ts:**

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, UsePipes, ValidationPipe, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SubcategoriesService } from './subcategories.service';
import { Subcategory } from './subcategory.entity';
import { RestController } from '../rest.controller';
import { CreateSubcategoryDTO } from './dto/createSubcategory.dto';

//NOTE THE TYPE PARAMS IN <>
@Controller('subcategories')
export class SubcategoriesController extends RestController<Subcategory, CreateSubcategoryDTO> {
  constructor(public service: SubcategoriesService) {
    super(service);
  }    
}
```

**subcategories.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Subcategory } from './subcategory.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { RestService } from '../rest.service';
import { CreateSubcategoryDTO } from './dto/createSubcategory.dto';

//NOTE THE TYPE PARAMS IN <>
@Injectable()
export class SubcategoriesService extends RestService<Subcategory, CreateSubcategoryDTO> {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Subcategory) repository: Repository<Subcategory>,
  ) {
    super(repository);
  }
}
```

**createSubcategory.dto.ts**

```
import { IsString, Length, IsInt } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateSubcategoryDTO {

  @IsString()
  @Length(5, 60)
  name: string;

  @IsString()
  @Length(0, 140)
  summary: string;

  @Length(0, 140)
  icon: string;

  @IsInt()
  category: number;
}
```

You can see that the parent class accepts 3 types parameters:

- `T` : the Entity
- `C` : the CreateDTO, optional
- `U` : the UpdateDTO, optional

The code above creates the endpoints perfectly, however **it does not validate the payload** in the `/create`, as expected from the *ValidationPipe*.

**If I overwrite** the *create* method in the SubcategoriesController, and add the UsePipes there, **it works**!

I think this may be an error referring to Nests lifecycle, which may not support the use of Pipes in abstract classes.

Does someone have an idea?

**P.S**. There are no transpilation errors, lint warnings or runtime exceptions.

Comment: I am in the same situation, how did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

One solution to this is to create a factory function for your controllers that will accept your body param class as an argument and then pass it to a custom ValidationPipe extension like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AbstractValidationPipe extends ValidationPipe {
  constructor(
    options: ValidationPipeOptions,
    private readonly targetTypes: {
      body?: Type<any>;
      query?: Type<any>;
      param?: Type<any>;
      custom?: Type<any>;
    },
  ) {
    super(options);
  }

  async transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const targetType = this.targetTypes[metadata.type];
    if (!targetType) {
      return super.transform(value, metadata);
    }
    return super.transform(value, { ...metadata, metatype: targetType });
  }
}

export interface IController<T> {
  hello(body: T);
}

export function Factory<T>(bodyDto: ClassType<T>): ClassType<IController<T>> {
  @Controller()
  class ControllerHost<T> implements IController<T> {
    @Post()
    @UsePipes(new AbstractValidationPipe({whitelist: true, transform: true}, {body: bodyDto}))
    hello(@Body() body: T) {
      return "hello"
    }
  }
  return ControllerHost;
}

export class MyDto {
  @Expose()
  @IsDefined()
  @IsString()
  hello: string;
}

export class AppController extends Factory<MyDto>(MyDto) {}
```

There is no information on generics available with Reflection so standard ValidationPipe is not getting any meaningful information from `metadata.metatype`. I'm working around this by providing it with optional types params that it can use to overwrite the content of `metadata.metatype`. It has this nice feature that it will work for normal use cases (without generics) too. If you want to overwrite `query` or `param` too just provided appropriate values through `targetTypes` param.

Comment: oh great,you saved my time;  for those who dont know what is ClassType => `export type ClassType<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;`

Answer (score 0):

you are probably looking for InheritValidation decorator

https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/blob/master/test/functional/inherited-validation.spec.ts