# NestJs reusable controller with validation

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

Most of my NestJs controllers look the same. They have basic CRUD functionality and do the exact same things.

The only differences between the controllers are:

- the path
- the service that is injected (and the services are all extended from an abstract service)
- the entity that is returned from the methods
- the create, update, and query dtos

Here is an example CRUD controller:

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Controller("/api/warehouse/goods-receipts")
export class GoodsReceiptsController
  implements ICrudController<GoodsReceipt, CreateGoodsReceiptDto, UpdateGoodsReceiptDto, QueryGoodsReceiptDto> {
  constructor(private service: GoodsReceiptsService) {
  }

  @Post()
  create(@Body() body: CreateGoodsReceiptDto, @CurrentUser() user: Partial<User>): Promise<GoodsReceipt> {
    return this.service.createItem(body, user);
  }

  @Delete(":id")
  delete(@Param() params: NumberIdDto): Promise<Partial<GoodsReceipt>> {
    return this.service.deleteItem(params.id);
  }

  @Get(":id")
  getOne(@Param() params: NumberIdDto): Promise<GoodsReceipt> {
    return this.service.getItem(params.id);
  }

  @Get()
  get(@Query() query: QueryGoodsReceiptDto): Promise<GoodsReceipt[]> {
    return this.service.getItems(query);
  }

  @Patch()
  update(@Body() body: UpdateGoodsReceiptDto, @CurrentUser() user: Partial<User>): Promise<GoodsReceipt> {
    return this.service.updateItem(body,user);
  }
}
```

This is the interface I have created for my controllers:

```
export interface ICrudController<EntityType, CreateDto, UpdateDto, QueryDto> {

  getOne(id: NumberIdDto): Promise<EntityType>;

  get(query: QueryDto): Promise<EntityType[]>;

  create(body: CreateDto, user: Partial<User>): Promise<EntityType>;

  update(body: UpdateDto, user: Partial<User>): Promise<EntityType>;

  delete(id: NumberIdDto): Promise<Partial<EntityType>>;
}
```

Writing all these repetitive controllers has got pretty tiresome (yes I know about `nest g resource` but that is not really the point of this question), so I decided to create an abstract controller that will do most of the heavy lifting and have the controllers extend this.

```
export abstract class CrudController<T, C, U, Q> implements ICrudController<T, C, U, Q> {
  protected service: ICrudService<T, C, U, Q>;

  @Post()
  create(@Body() body: C, @CurrentUser() user: Partial<User>): Promise<T> {
    return this.service.createItem(body, user);
  }

  @Get(":id")
  getOne(@Param() params: NumberIdDto): Promise<T> {
    return this.service.getItem(params.id);
  }

  @Get()
  get(@Query() query: Q): Promise<T[]> {
    return this.service.getItems(query);
  }

  @Delete(":id")
  delete(@Param() params: NumberIdDto): Promise<Partial<T>> {
    return this.service.deleteItem(params.id);
  }

  @Patch()
  update(@Body() body: U, @CurrentUser() user: Partial<User>): Promise<T> {
    return this.service.updateItem(body, user);
  }
}
```

Now all I need to do to add a new controller is this:

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Controller("/api/warehouse/goods-receipts")
export class GoodsReceiptsController
  extends CrudController<GoodsReceipt, CreateGoodsReceiptDto, UpdateGoodsReceiptDto, QueryGoodsReceiptDto> {
  constructor(protected service: GoodsReceiptsService) {
    super();
  }
}
```

I was very proud of myself at that point. That is until I figured out that validation no longer works because class-validator doesn't work with generic types.

There has to be some way I could fix this with minimal intervention and maximal use of reusable code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have managed to make it work using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64802874/1320704

The trick is to create a controller factory, and use a custom validation pipe.

Here is the solution:

```
@Injectable()
export class AbstractValidationPipe extends ValidationPipe {
  constructor(
    options: ValidationPipeOptions,
    private readonly targetTypes: { body?: Type; query?: Type; param?: Type; }
  ) {
    super(options);
  }

  async transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const targetType = this.targetTypes[metadata.type];
    if (!targetType) {
      return super.transform(value, metadata);
    }
    return super.transform(value, { ...metadata, metatype: targetType });
  }
}

export function ControllerFactory<T, C, U, Q>(
  createDto: Type<C>,
  updateDto: Type<U>,
  queryDto: Type<Q>
): ClassType<ICrudController<T, C, U, Q>> {
  const createPipe = new AbstractValidationPipe({ whitelist: true, transform: true }, { body: createDto });
  const updatePipe = new AbstractValidationPipe({ whitelist: true, transform: true }, { body: updateDto });
  const queryPipe = new AbstractValidationPipe({ whitelist: true, transform: true }, { query: queryDto });

  class CrudController<T, C, U, Q> implements ICrudController<T, C, U, Q> {
    protected service: ICrudService<T, C, U, Q>;

    @Post()
    @UsePipes(createPipe)
    async create(@Body() body: C, @CurrentUser() user: Partial<User>): Promise<T> {
      return this.service.createItem(body, user);
    }

    @Get(":id")
    getOne(@Param() params: NumberIdDto): Promise<T> {
      return this.service.getItem(params.id);
    }

    @Get()
    @UsePipes(queryPipe)
    get(@Query() query: Q): Promise<T[]> {
      return this.service.getItems(query);
    }

    @Delete(":id")
    delete(@Param() params: NumberIdDto): Promise<Partial<T>> {
      return this.service.deleteItem(params.id);
    }

    @Patch()
    @UsePipes(updatePipe)
    update(@Body() body: U, @CurrentUser() user: Partial<User>): Promise<T> {
      return this.service.updateItem(body, user);
    }
  }

  return CrudController;
}
```

And to create the actual controller you simply pass the desired dtos to the factory:

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Controller("/api/warehouse/goods-receipts")
export class GoodsReceiptsController
  extends ControllerFactory<GoodsReceipt, CreateGoodsReceiptDto, UpdateGoodsReceiptDto, QueryGoodsReceiptDto>
  (CreateGoodsReceiptDto,UpdateGoodsReceiptDto,QueryGoodsReceiptDto){
  constructor(protected service: GoodsReceiptsService) {
    super();
  }
}
```

You can also optionally pass the response entity type into the factory and use that with the @ApiResponse tag if you use swagger.
Also you could pass the path to the factory and move all the decorators (Controller, UseGuards etc.) to the factory controller definition.

Comment: Can you clarify what is ClassType?

Comment: @MML1357 I think it came from swagger or graphql package. I have since replaced it with `Type` from `@nestjs/common`

Comment: I'm using swagger. On the create, when I Try, the textarea to insert the body doesn't show.

Comment: You need to add the `@ApiBody` decorator to the factory create function. `@ApiBody({ type: createDto })` You also need to add another argument in the factory constructor where you pass the entity type, then add `@ApiResponse({ type: entityType })` so swagger knows what the endpoint returns. Other decorators you might find useful are `@ApiParam`, `@ApiQuery` etc.

Comment: that works, now the schema is displayed but... the controller it's no catching the body value. If I do a
`console.log(body)`
it shows only `CreateAreaDto {}`. CreateAreaDto is the Dto I'm passing as C.

Comment: Did you decorate the fields in your DTO with `@ApiProperty`? Or if you don't want to do that you can enable the swagger plugin in nest-cli.json.